# Radeditor image manager upload button enabled

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I want to enabled my RadEditor Upload button. Currently it is disabled as you can see in screen. I want to enabled it. I have made lots of customization. Please correct me where I am wrong. Any help much appreciated. I look forward to have an answers. I also given permission "Everyone" to my img folder which is just outside where my ascx file is. Another imp thing is, I am not getting Upload button at all in Edit mode whereas I am getting Upload button in disabled mode during Add. This is quite strange for me.

```
[RadEditor_ImageManager_Uploadbutton][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzjCt.png

Here is the code I have written, in ascx file.
=======
<telerik:radeditor runat="server" id="tbcontent" AllowScripts="True" content='<%#Bind("content") %>' DialogHandlerUrl="~/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" class="HtmlEditor"><ImageManager UploadPaths="~/img" DeletePaths="~/img" ViewPaths="~/img" MaxUploadFileSize="10240000"  SearchPatterns="*.gif, *.jpg, *.jpe, *.jpeg, *.tiff, *.tif,*.bmp"/></telerik:radeditor>
======

There is a code in my web.config file.
=======
<location path="admin/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow roles="TestUser"/>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    </location> 
    <location path="admin/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow roles="TestUser"/>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    </location>
-----
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

            <remove name="ScriptModule" />
            <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral  />

            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression"/>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        </modules>
----
<handlers>
<add name="ChartImage.axd_*" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral,  preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral,  preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral,  preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
------
<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI"/>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral,  validate="false"></add>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, ></add>
      <add verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral,  validate="false"/>
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false"/>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>

</httpHandlers>
-----
======

Anybody tell me what's wrong with this, Why Upload button is disabled?

Appreciate your help as early as possible.

Thanks,
Harshal
```

Answer (score 0):

ensure you use the AsyncUpload:

```
        <telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server">
            <ImageManager EnableAsyncUpload="true" />
        </telerik:RadEditor>
```

Allow access to everyone for all handlers, e.g.:

```
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

and the rest of the handlers from this list: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/web-config-settings-overview#mandatory-additions-to-the-webconfig

Copy the handlers list for your web.config from that article as yours do not use proper fully qualified assembly names, nor non-qualified assembly names.